# Can QGIS be installed on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I cannot find a repository for QGIS (2.18 or LTR 2.14) compatible with the latest Ubuntu distro (17.04) in any of the PPA's listed in the [installer docs](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). Do I have to wait for a 17.04 supported release, or is there perhaps a workaround?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+source/qgis but beware of the known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qgis

Comment: @Mapperz - the main repo install of 2.14 does indeed work & no bug for me so far.  Add your comment as an answer & I'll accept it, many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS LTR (2.14) is in the main 17.04 repository.

The repository for QGIS latest release (http://qgis.org/debian) currently provides a QGIS 2.18 package for 16.10 but not 17.04, and the 16.10 package won't install on 17.04.

The nightlies for the upcoming point release are available for 17.04, though. Currently that's the only way to install 2.18 for Zesty from a repo. The usual cautions about installing nightly builds apply. `deb http://qgis.org/debian-nightly-release zesty main`

Since 17.04 is available in the nightlies, the main repository will presumably include a 17.04 package for the next point release for 2.18.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: The QGIS debian repo now has QGIS 2.18.7 for zesty as well, so no need to test the nightlies.